# Show all workspaces on i3

Tags: i3

I am starting to use and configure i3 and I have searched if it is possible to show all workspaces even though they are blank but I have not found a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In i3, you can create any number of workspaces. At any time, you can only see the workspaces you've applications on.
When i3 starts, only one workspace per monitor is displayed.

Here's my i3 config for creating workspaces upto 20, if that helps

```
# workspaces from 11-20
bindsym $mod+Control+1 workspace 11
bindsym $mod+Control+2 workspace 12
bindsym $mod+Control+3 workspace 13
bindsym $mod+Control+4 workspace 14
bindsym $mod+Control+5 workspace 15
bindsym $mod+Control+6 workspace 16
bindsym $mod+Control+7 workspace 17
bindsym $mod+Control+8 workspace 18
bindsym $mod+Control+9 workspace 19
bindsym $mod+Control+0 workspace 20

set $Lmon eDP-1-1
set $Rmon HDMI-0
 
workspace $ws1 output $Lmon
 
workspace $ws3 output $Lmon
 
workspace $ws5 output $Lmon
 
workspace $ws7 output $Lmon
 
workspace $ws9 output $Lmon
 
workspace $ws2 output $Rmon
 
workspace $ws4 output $Rmon
 
workspace $ws6 output $Rmon
 
workspace $ws8 output $Rmon
 
workspace $ws10 output $Rmon

workspace 11 output $Lmon
workspace 12 output $Rmon
workspace 13 output $Lmon
workspace 14 output $Rmon
workspace 15 output $Lmon
workspace 16 output $Rmon
workspace 17 output $Lmon
workspace 18 output $Rmon
workspace 19 output $Lmon
workspace 20 output $Rmon
```

Even number workspaces are displayed on my right monitor and odd number workspaces are displayed on left monitor

Comment: My left monitor has 1 through 5 and 6 to 10 goes in the right

Answer (score 0):

By the design of how i3 works, there is virtually no limit on how many workspaces could possibly exist. So showing all potential workspaces is impossible. There seems to be some talk online on a patch that allows a few empty workspaces to not get deleted but I don't think it was ever implemented.
If you just want a couple of your workspaces to always be available, you could always just open applications in some of these workspaces on startup in your i3 config. Is there anything specific you're trying to do with these open empty workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

It's dirty hack - move some app after i3 startup by all needed workspaces. i3 do not delete already created workspaces in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As [kapa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63731272/14810866) said, it is impossible (assuming you use i3bar). But as [H4K1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64484809/14810866) points out, there are other bars with this kind of option.

I use polybar, and I can tell you there is a `pin-workspaces` option in the `[module/i3]` section that can be set to `true`, allowing at least 10 workspaces to be visible from startup (empty or not).

Comment: pin-workspaces not work with me, i3-gaps

Comment: I don't know why people think polybar can do this. Those empty workspaces don't exist within i3 and polybar just queries i3 for the list of workspaces.

Answer (score -1):

You can try it with [polybar](https://github.com/polybar/polybar), if this doesn't work the only solution I know of is to use [bspwm](https://github.com/baskerville/bspwm), because it shows empty workspaces

Comment: Can you maybe include a piece of code example. It is better to share code and then share the link example afterwards.